# The norm of Bessel potentials

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

I'm studying the theory of Bessel potentials $J_\alpha$ and I'm reading the proof of their strong(p,p) regularity:

> (Theorem) Let $\alpha>0$. Then, $J_\alpha : L^p\rightarrow L^p$ for all
> $p\in[1,+\infty]$ and $||J_\alpha||_{op}=1$.

where $J_\alpha(f)=G_\alpha\ast f$ (initially for all $f$ Schwartz function) and $G_\alpha(x)$ as the inverse Fourier transform of the tempered distribution induced by $(1+4\pi^2|\cdot|^2)^{-\alpha/2}$.

The only problem I got is that they justify the fact that $||J_\alpha||_{op}=1$ with the only fact that "$G_\alpha>0$ for $\alpha>0$" (and I know this is true). But I can't see how these two thing are related.

We know that for $\alpha>0$, $G_\alpha\in C^\infty(R^n\setminus\{0\})$ and
\begin{equation}
G_\alpha(x)\leq C_\alpha e^{-|x|/2}
\end{equation}
for $|x|\geq1$. Also, for $\alpha>n$, $G_\alpha$ is continuous and, hence, limited and $\forall 0<\alpha\leq n$ $G_\alpha$ has the same order of growth of
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-log|x| & \text{$\alpha=n$}\\
1/|x|^{n-\alpha} & \text{$0<\alpha<n$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $|x|\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Of course, it is not sufficient to use only this property. For example $2 G_\alpha$ is also positive but the associated operator norm is $2$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some more context, in particular where you were reading this proof.

Comment: I saw this "proof" on my teacher's notes (and, believe in me, this was the only explanation written there), and I don't really know what else I could say to provide a better context... $J_\alpha$ (the Bessel potential) is defined exactly as $J_\alpha(f)=G_\alpha\ast f$ for all $f\in S$ (the Schwartz space) and we only know that $G_\alpha$ is actually a smooth function and I have edited my question giving you its behavior at infinity and at 0.

Comment: It's true and obvious that, using those infos about $G_\alpha$'s behavior that it is $L^1$, so that $||G_\alpha||_1=\hat{G}_\alpha(0)=1$ since $G_\alpha>0$ and the boundedness follows from Young's inequality (so that $||J_\alpha f||_p\leq||f||_p\cdot 1$ i.e. $||J_\alpha||_{op}\leq1$). But, then, he just states that it is $=1$ since $G_\alpha>0$.

Comment: The positivity of $G_{\alpha}$ implies that the operator norm on $L^1$ is $1$, by considering the action on nonnegative functions. And the operator norm on $L^2$ is also $1$ in light of the Fourier multiplier. The rest you might be able to get via interpolation arguments.